# D3 Graphs and Charts in nancyfx

Tags: d3.js, nancy

How to configure nancy to run an example like this one here
https://gist.github.com/mbostock/3305937.

The problem I have is that the data.tsv is not found.

Thank you.

Michael

Comment: See https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/wiki/Managing-static-content. If you put the `data.tsv` file in `/Content`, then you can access it using `d3.tsv("/Content/data.tsv", function(data) {...`

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick response. It is working now.